# Asp net password recovery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net membership for users accounts, user password is encrypted and stored on to the sql database as a user registers , the problem I'm having it  when the user forgets the password I can't get it right when trying to retrieve it from the database, I have no idea how I can reverse the encryption.I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. By default the passwords are saved as a salted SHA1 hash, you can't "decrypt" such a hash.

It would be bad practice to save passwords in a fashion that allows you to view them, no matter which algorithm you would be using for that. Just create some logic to enable a user to reset his or her password, instead of trying to retrieve the original password.

Comment: Ok thanks.do you happen to have some methods of how can one reset password?

Comment: @NjabuloMagwaza: have a look here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet